# access heroku DB via odbc on mac osx?

Tags: macos, odbc, heroku

we need to build a heroku app which stores data in a DB table. 
we have proprietary software that needs to connect via ODBC to the DB. 
what driver do we need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends if you are using a Shared or Dedicated database as to whether this is possible.

[via the Heroku Dev Center](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/external-database-access)